# What caused the delay of DL49 AMS-JFK 08-08-2017?

Tags: air-travel, compensation, delta-air-lines

On 8-8-2017, DL49 was delayed, causing me to miss my connection at JFK and arriving 6 hours late at final destination.

According to KLM, the delay was due to late arrival of the aircraft due to weather. Not true, the aircraft left the gate on time, but was on the runway for almost 1.5 hours, due to brakes needing to cool down. This information was given by the pilot.

What can I do to claim compensation?

Comment: I'd contact KLM directly: 
https://www.klm.com/travel/ca_en/customer_support/customer_support/refunds_and_compensation/index.htm

Comment: You might like to cross-post to Aviation to see if the brakes cooling story might be obviously not true.

Comment: You can check out the historical data on Flightradar24 with a gold subscription. This will let you see the “official” departure / arrival times. You’ll also be able to look up the previous movement of the aircraft. Also where was the weather problem? I believe a recent case says that only the weather at the airports directly involved in the flight is an excuse.

Comment: Do you mean "taxiway"? No plane would ever be allowed to be on a runway for 1.5 hours unless it was incapable of moving or being towed. Did the plane have a rejected takeoff? That's the usual reason for brakes needing to cool down.

Comment: "According to KLM" - did you apply for compensation and got this response from them?

Comment: Yes this was KLM's second response. They first blamed it on `extraordinary` circumstances ....

Comment: The weather at SPL was fine, nice summer weather, no rain

Comment: Why do you think "brakes needed time to cool down" contradicts "late arrival"? They seem perfectly compatible to me: the aircraft arrived late, so the brakes didn't have enough time to cool down before the next scheduled departure.

Comment: TBH this seems like a rant disguised as a question.

Comment: The pilot made this announcement after the aircraft left the gate ....

Comment: FYA: I have asked a meta question about the topicality of this question.

Comment: Thank you CG Campbell, did you get any helpful responses?

Comment: "Why was the flight delayed?" and "How can I get compensation?" are two completely different questions. Which are you actually asking? If the former, it's unlikely that anyone would be able to find out. Unless the delay was noteworthy enough to be covered in the news media, it's unlikely that there'll be any publicly available record, especially with the flight being so long ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not totally about travel and seems to be more a rant to file a claim

Comment: OP has not returned to answer clarifications/questions from comments. Put on hold for now.  Would be good to edit questions to be on one topic/question only, with more detail about the flight and timing of announcements.

Comment: Delay of flight DL49 on 08/08/2017 was investigated by ILT (Human Environment and Transport Inspectorate, of the Dutch Ministry of Infrastructure and Water Management). Conclusion: technical issue.